# How to use the laravel command 'whereIn' and 'WhereNotIn' in the same query on laravel collection

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have a query that works fine when randomly selecting a new product from the database. But to prevent duplication, in my view I pass a JSON object of products already for sale on the page. I want my query to essentially query my DB for products for sale but are also not in the collection of products already for sale.

This part works absolutely fine

```
$nproduct = Product::whereIn('seller_id', Auth::user()->samegroup())->inRandomOrder()->first();
            $nprice = $nproduct->price;
            $nquantity = $nproduct->quantity_available;
            $nid = $nproduct->id;
            $nseller = $nproduct->seller_id;
```

But I struggle when trying to make sure my query doesn't include anything inside $products_already_for_sale

```
$products_already_for_sale = $request->current_product_ids;
```

Comment: Why are you doing `whereIn` with `first()`? `whereIn` is for when you have multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$products_already_for_sale = $request->current_product_ids; //it must be array []

$nproduct = Product::whereIn('seller_id', Auth::user()->samegroup())->whereNotIn('product_id',
$products_already_for_sale)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

totally untested, but I think this would work